# Date/Time error when entering into azure incorrectly

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to add 2 DateTime fields which are stored as strings in Azure. The first datetime is supposed to get the current date and time now and this stores the date time as 12/02/2019 09:01 correctly, but currently the second field is supposed to get the current date and time and add 30 minutes but it is storing is like only the date eg 12/02/2019. This is my current code:

```
symptomFeedback.DateTime = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm");
symptomFeedback.Datetimelimit = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm");
```

Comment: Probably because the Azure host is in a different timezone. Since you are not specifying any timezone information, it assumes it is local and changes it. Try to convert it to UTC.

Comment: But why is the time format not being entered into azure for the second field but it is for the first ?